# How much should I write about the competing policies?

Tags: citations, writing, literature, political-science

I'm working on a political science problem that has attracted (by my count) fourteen proposed solutions, ranging from somewhat useful to positively harmful. Some are already law in many countries; others are recent inventions, advanced in papers and amicus briefs by eminent scientists. Several survey papers enumerate these strategies.

My paper recombines three of the methods in a formal relationship. To use this model, the eleven alternatives and all the laws that follow from them must be jettisoned. Some parties (not just authors, but political interests) are sure to defend them.

How much should I write about the competing policies?

Comment: I don't think we will be able to help you very much here. On the one hand, if a lot of stuff needs to be jettisoned in favor of your approach, you will need to defend your approach and explain how it is better than the ones you want to throw overboard, so you will certainly need to discuss them to this extent. Then again, how verbose you can be (or are expected to be) will certainly depend on the venue you are aiming for.